# Efficient query in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-delete, database-performance

Can anyone think of a better way to write below query in SQL Server, since this one does a full table scan?

```
DELETE FROM tablename
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM view a, tablename b
              WHERE (a.rk = b.rk
                AND a.tdate = b.tdate
                AND a.locid = b.locid
                AND a.itemid = b.itemid))
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: @marc_s soon you can start saying more than 25 years ago :-) i feel old now

Comment: Your query at the moment won't do what you want anyway. It will delete either the whole table or nothing. Depending on  whether or not the non correlated query returns a row.

Comment: it does what I want but takes forever

Comment: how many rows does it delete? sometime you have to delete in chunk i had to do that with a 25 millions rows table one time

Comment: You want to delete every row in the table?

Comment: I have to delete around 2million rows in a 70 million table

Comment: read this http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1750/methods-of-speeding-up-a-huge-delete-from-table-with-no-clauses but please double check that query before running it

Comment: That query won't delete only 2 million. It is going to delete all 70 million. And to delete 2 million rows I would suggest batching it because that is a huge strain on the transaction log and tempdb.

Comment: i hope you had a transaction that you rolledback or your test was on a test DB, if not you have lost data now.

Comment: It is a test db and it deleted ONLY 2 million in 5 hrs

Comment: I know it is very inefficient , that's why I'm looking for a better way

Comment: These kinda of question belong more at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ then here.

Comment: go read the link that i have posted above, this is how

Comment: That is not how that query is going to work. My guess is your actual query is different than this one. The one posted here will delete every single row in the table if there is a matching row in the second table. And batching this in smaller groups with a loop will be faster. Large deletes like this is one of the rare times that looping makes sense.

Comment: You have to look into your where clause or filter criteria before optimizing the query because you are doing delete everything or none, which is not satisfying your statement of deleting 2 million records out of 70 million records.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL server, delete statements can have joins.

```
DELETE tbl
FROM tablename tbl
    INNER JOIN VIEW a ON (
        a.rk = tbl.rk 
        AND a.tdate = tbl.tdate
        AND a.locid = tbl.locid
        AND a.itemid = tbl.itemid);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just select the ID's you want to delete, assuming you have a primary key of "ID"...

As some have suggested, you could delete in groups, by selecting the top 1000, 10000, 100000, etc.)

```
DELETE FROM tablename
WHERE tablename.ID in (SELECT TOP 1000 b.ID 
                       FROM tablename b
                          INNER JOIN view a 
                            ON a.rk = b.rk
                                AND a.tdate = b.tdate
                                AND a.locid = b.locid
                                AND a.itemid = b.itemid)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a batching script that should do what you want.

```
DECLARE @del_query VARCHAR(MAX)

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmp_delete') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tmp_delete
SELECT Tablename.ID INTO #tmp_delete FROM tablename b
                          INNER JOIN view a 
                            ON a.rk = b.rk
                                AND a.tdate = b.tdate
                                AND a.locid = b.locid
                                AND a.itemid = b.itemid

SET @del_query ='
DELETE TOP(1000) tn
FROM Tablename tn 
INNER JOIN #tmp_delete t ON t.id = tn.id'
WHILE 1 = 1
BEGIN
    EXEC(@del_query + ' option(maxdop 5) ')
    IF @@rowcount < 1000 BREAK;
END
```

Comment: I prefer to use a while exists instead of while 1 = 1 and then a break. while exists (select * from table join #tmp_delete...) And definitely no need for dynamic sql inside.

Comment: @sean I've used that before in the following: 
    Select 1
    While @@ROWCOUNT > 0
    BEGIN
    delete Top (1000)
    
    I've found the method I've posted to work faster on deletes then the WHILE statement.